# Sound library organizer free

Tags: gratis, library, osx, audio-recording

I'm starting doing a lot of random field recording and my library is getting a bit messy.

Could you suggest me a good software to edit metadata/organise the recordings in categories or something like that. How do you do it?

ps. I'm on a mac and don't have much money so free/cheap software appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Audiofinder](http://www.icedaudio.com/site/) by Iced Audio. Not free, but certainly good value.